# Passing a predefined variable as a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, pic, mplab

I tried to write a PIC program with C and what it does is turn on a series of 8 LED's (like Knight Rider LED illumination :D ). I have created the circuit design and tested with a simple c program that sets the state of the lights and it works. Now I want to streamline my code.

So i have created 2 functions for delaying and getting the required HEX value of the LED. the 2 methods are like this.

```
#define MAX 8
#define LEFT 1
#define RIGHT 2
#define BOTH 0

void delay_ms(int ms) {
    while(ms > 0)
        ms--;
}

int getHex(int delay, int dir, int *pin) {
    int hex[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80};

    if (dir == RIGHT) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            *pin = hex[i];
            delay_ms(delay);
        }
    } else if( dir == LEFT ) {
        for (int i = MAX - 1; i == 0; i--)
        {
            pin = hex[i];
            delay_ms(delay);
        }
    }
}
```

and i have this in the main() function

```
main() {
    TRISA = 1;
    TRISB = 0;

    while(1) {

        if(RA0 == 0)
            getHex(5000, RIGHT, PORTB);
    }
}
```

What im trying to do is pass the `PORTB` predefined variable as a pointer to the function so it is set with the proper hex value. But i get the following warnings when i compile with the MPLAB IDE,

```
Warning [357] D:\...\main.c; 24.13 illegal conversion of integer to pointer
Warning [357] D:\...\main.c; 37.22 illegal conversion of integer to pointer
```

and when the program hex is added and run in the `Proteus 8` nothing happens and the following warning appears.

```
[PIC16 MEMORY]PC=0x03AF. Attempt to write unimplemented memory location 0x0087 with 0x01 ignored
[PIC16 MEMORY]PC=0x03AF. Attempt to write unimplemented memory location 0x0087 with 0x02 ignored
[PIC16 MEMORY]PC=0x03AF. Attempt to write unimplemented memory location 0x0087 with 0x04 ignored
```

the final Hex value in the error correspond with the hex value i am trying to set as the value of `PORTB`. What am i doing wrong.. Please help.

Comment: `&42` makes no sense. Values do not have addresses.

Comment: Please show the definition of `PORTB`

Comment: I found this online, This renames the `PORTB`. `static volatile unsigned char LCDOUT @ (unsigned)&PORTB;` Here is the [link](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m580522.aspx)

Comment: That's some extension of your compiler; it's not standard C

Comment: The `@` non-standard extension usually means "allocate this variable at (@) this address".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the getHex Method definition to this.

```
int getHex(int delay, int dir, int *pin) {
    int hex[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80};

    if (dir == RIGHT) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            *pin = hex[i];
            delay_ms(delay);
        }
    } else if( dir == LEFT ) {
        for (int i = MAX - 1; i == 0; i--)
        {
            *pin = hex[i];
            delay_ms(delay);
        }
    }
}
```

and then called the function with the following..

```
getHex(2000, RIGHT, &PORTB);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways that such pre-defined registers may be declared. I don't know how Mplab does it, but the most common way is this:

```
#define PORTB (*(volatile uint8_t*)0x1234)
```

where 0x1234 is the hardware address of that register. This macro accesses the register directly, but the `*` to the left makes it so that you can use the macro as if PORTB was an ordinary variable and not a pointer.

If this is the case, then you need to pass `&PORTB` to your function that expects a pointer.